# require is not defined using rollup

Tags: configuration, commonjs, rollupjs

I have the following `rollup.config.js`:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'input.js',
  output: {
    file: 'output.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(
      {
        jsnext: true,
        main: true
      }
    ),
    commonjs({ include: 'hello.js' })
  ]
}
```

I have the following `input.js` which `require`s `hello.js`:

```
var hello = require('./hello.js');

console.log(hello);
```

and `hello.js` is simply:

```
module.exports = 'hello';
```

I would like `output.js` to not include the `require` syntax and for it to be replaced it with the string `'hello'`.

I instead still see the line `var hello = require('./hello.js');`

How can I replace this line with a rollup plugin? (I thought that is what the commonjs plugin was for).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out.

The problem was with my `input.js` file.

The plugin doesn't support `require`, but the plugin facilitates `module.exports`.

Changing `input.js` to be:

```
import x from './hello.js';

console.log(x);
```

worked.

Comment: More specifically, the issue appears to be that the CommonJS plugin had `include: 'hello.js'` — in other words it was excluding `input.js`. The plugin *does* translate `require` as well as `module.exports`, but only for the files it's applied to ;)

Comment: Sadly, the question how to get `require` to be properly handled by rollup is not answered by this answer. @RichHarris any chance you can advise on how to get rid of `require` in the output?